# cq5 <cq:include> not working

Tags: extjs, aem

I have **included a component in another component jsp** using

```
<cq:include path="navMenu" resourceType="/apps/project/components/common/testMenu" />
```

getting the following error :

> http://localhost:4502/content/testsite/en/about/jcr:content/headernav/navMenu.infinity.json? 404 (Not Found)
>
> I am having the same issues with all the components when used
>   `<cq:include>` tag inside another component jsp.

scenario:

- component1 with sling:resourceSuperType to parentcomponent
- cq:include    subcomponent inside component1
- page -> drag and drop the component1 or include it.

I appreciate any help on this.

Thank you,
Sri

**Error:**
[image]

**Success - drag and drop individual component**
[image]

Comment: resourceType is without /apps/, so try to simply use resourceType="project/components/common/testMenu"
Then the next question would by, does your component call this JSON? Or when exactly do you get this error?

Comment: @Thomas I tried without /apps/ but no success. I put an image in my question to give the clarity.  This issue happening in a scenario, where multiple components formed inheritance through sling:resourceSuperType and a child component including a common component using cq:include tag. This issue does not happen, if I drag and drop common component onto the page, please see success image.

Comment: this seems like something is missing in the inheritance, e.g. some intermediary nodes are not present. Maybe your inheriting component needs a cq:template where missing nodes are created.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the initial "/" like
    `<cq:include path="navMenu" resourceType="apps/project/components/common/testMenu" />`

Also give relative path as`<cq:include path="navMenu" resourceType="project/components/common/testMenu" />`